# Make single row of multiple rows by appending to the right in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql, reporting-services

I have a table such as this:

```
UserID  AddressLine1, AddressLine2, Phone
1, First Street, Somewhere, 123
1, Second Street, Somewhere2, 124
2, 32th Street, Somewhere, 125
2, 24th Street, Somewhere3, 126
2, 25th Street, Somewhere4, 127
```

How do I convert this to (Output needs to have each field in separate column, each comma implies a column de-limiter):

```
1, First Street, Somewhere, 123, Second Street, Somewhere2, 124
2, 32th Street, Somewhere, 125, 24th Street, Somewhere3, 126, 25th Street, Somewhere4, 127
```

This is for a report i am doing in SSRS.  Each user can have a dynamic number of addresses and they all need to be on a single row per user in the end result.

Answer (score 3):

This may not be the efficient way in `MSSQL` but give this a try.

```
SELECT  a.UserID, 
        SUBSTRING(d.Addresses,1, LEN(d.Addresses) - 1) AddressList
FROM 
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT UserID
            FROM   tableName
        ) a
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT [AddressLine1] + ', ' + [AddressLine2] + ', ' + CAST([Phone] as VARCHAR(15)) + ', ' 
            FROM tableName AS B 
            WHERE A.UserID = B.UserID 
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ) D (Addresses)
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b886d/18)

Comment: This works but can i get the result in separate columns instead of a concatenated string?

Comment: your question is not clear. i thought you want concatenated string result becuase of your outputted result. do you want all values to be in separate column?

Comment: Yes the output needs to be in separate columns.  Sorry I'll clarify the question.

Comment: @sylon i think it's "impossible" to do because the number of fields is dynamic in the sense that its basis is the number of records of the `USERID` multiplied by three. does the records of `userid` has limit of 3?

Comment: No there is no limit for the number of addresses.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Declare @t Table([UserID] int, [AddressLine1] varchar(20), [AddressLine2] varchar(20), [Phone] int);

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
    (1, 'First Street', 'Somewhere', 123),
    (1, 'Second Street', 'Somewhere2', 124),
    (2, '32th Street', 'Somewhere', 125),
    (2, '24th Street', 'Somewhere3', 126),
    (2, '25th Street', 'Somewhere4', 127);

SELECT 
      [UserID]
    , [New Address] = 

                    STUFF((
                            SELECT ',' 
                                    +  [AddressLine1] 
                                    + ', ' 
                                    + [AddressLine2] 
                                    + ', ' 
                                    + CAST([Phone] AS VARCHAR(10)) 
                          FROM @t AS t2 
                          WHERE t1.UserID = t2.UserID 
                          FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
FROM @t t1
GROUP BY t1.[UserID]
```

//Result

**UserID    New Address**

```
1   First Street, Somewhere, 123,Second Street, Somewhere2, 124
2   32th Street, Somewhere, 125,24th Street, Somewhere3, 126,25th Street, Somewhere4, 127
```

Apart from the approach described here, there are many other ways of solving the same. It is worth mentioning at this juncture to look into [Concatenating Row Values in Transact-SQL](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/) article. It is an awesome article and please spend some time to go through it (if you have not already done so).

Hope this helps

Comment: This works but can i get the result in separate columns instead of a concatenated string?

Comment: I will definitely answer to your question, but ask it in a separate thread. As per the question asked, both the answers presented here is correct. So please accept the answer of your choice for the current question and ask a new question in a separate thread for your  new requirement.